# Sort a list read from a file?

Tags: python

```
def insertionSort(a):
    for i in range(1, len(a)): #outer loop covering the range
        value = a[i] #value = to list, which will compare items to the left
        i = i - 1 #i goes lower than index to compare further to the left
        while i >= 0 : #keep comparing till its at the beginning of the list
            if value < a[i]: #if value is less than i
                a[i+1] = a[i] # shift number in right i to slot i + 1
                a[i] = value # shift value that was left into slot i
                i = i - 1
            else:
                break

infile = open("file1.txt", "r")
a=[]
for aline in infile:
    a = aline.split()

insertionSort(a)
print(a)
```

This is what is in the file:

```
7686850495948548545
```

How do I get the `insertionSort()` function to work on a file?

Comment: Does the file contain all numbers in one line?

Comment: when you do `a = aline.split()` it does not keep a reference outside the variable `a` so next iteration in the for loop overrides it with the next line, so what ends up happening is you only call the sort on **the last line of the file.**

Comment: if you instead did `a.extend(aline.split())` you would extend the list by all the words (or numbers) in that line and end up with all of them after the for loop.

Comment: One significant problem is that `'7686850495948548545\n'.split()` -> `['7686850495948548545']`. You probably want `list('7686850495948548545\n'.rstrip())` -> `['7', '6', '8', '6', '8', '5', '0', '4', '9', '5', '9', '4', '8', '5', '4', '8', '5', '4', '5']`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part is not quite right.

```
infile = open("file1.txt", "r")
a=[]
for aline in infile:
    a = aline.split()
```

The preferred way of opening and reading(or writing) a file is the following:

```
with open('some_file.txt', 'r') as in_file:
  string_numbers = in_file.read()
```

Then, once you have the numbers in a string, you can split them into a list like so:

```
nums_list = list(string_nums)
```

So `nums_list` is now a list of string, convert them to ints with list comprehension:

```
nums = [int(num) for num in nums_list]
```

**EDIT:**

just for fun, here's the concise version:

```
with open('filename.txt') as in_file:
  nums = [int(n) for n in list(in_file.read().strip())]
```

`.strip()` added just to ensure no strange whitespace casting.

Comment: `string_nums.split()` doesn't do what you think. Check out the result of `'7686850495948548545'.split()` in the Python console.

Comment: You're absolutely, correct, I meant `list(string_nums)`.  Thanks, edited.

Answer (score 0):

One of your problems is you're repeatedly assigning to `a`. That isn't what you want. Right now you start by assigning an empty list to `a`. Then you assign each line, broken up, to `a`, every time replacing what was previously assigned to `a`. I think what you actually want inside your for loop is:

```
a.extend(aline.split())
```

Fix that and let us know how well your code runs then.